# regex to not match if there exist subsequent characters after a certain character is found

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that will **not** result in a match if there exists subsequent text after a character is found after a certain pattern.

For example:

```py
/wiki/* => should match
/wiki/*/ => should match
/wiki/*/* => should NOT match
```

Consider `*` as any string made of characters allowed in a browser URL.

So basically anything with the form `/wiki/*` should match except if there exists a `/` in `*` followed by text.

I have been testing this on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) and so far I have tried:

```py
^\/wiki\/.*\/?[^.]*$
^\/wiki\/.*\/?[^.*]$
^\/wiki\/.*\/?(?!.)$
...
```

And many other variations of the above, but none of them work as expected.

Ultimately, I want to use this regex to match strings in python.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You just need to change your `.*` to `[^\]*`: [`^\/wiki\/[^/]*\/?$`](https://regex101.com/r/gGjw9j/1/)

Comment: I needed to scape the ```[^/]``` with ```[^\/]``` from your solution, but it works!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex `/^\/wiki\/[^\/]*\/?$/`. Test case:

```js
const regex = /^\/wiki\/[^\/]*\/?$/;
[
  '/wiki/aaa',
  '/wiki/aaa/',
  '/wiki/aaa/bbb'
].forEach(str => {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + regex.test(str))
});
```

Output:

```
/wiki/aaa => true
/wiki/aaa/ => true
/wiki/aaa/bbb => false
```

Explanation of regex of `/^\/wiki\/[^\/]*\/?$/`:

- `^` - anchor at start of string
- `\/wiki\/` - literal `/wiki/`
- `[^\/]*` - everything not `/`
- `\/?` - optional `/`
- `$` - anchor at end of string

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you explain why you have the ```[^\/]``` in that spot and the ```?``` at the end?